# Using math for negative minus negative

Tags: vb.net

this gives me 0 instead of -10. how can I fix it?

```
Dim aa As String = "-5"
Dim bb As String = "-5"
Debug.Print(Val(aa) - Val(bb))
```

Comment: fix what? (-5) - (-5) is 0. The program is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually Its correct

```
Dim aa As String = "-5"
Dim bb As String = "-5"
Debug.Print(Val(aa) - Val(bb))
```

If you want -10 then you need to add

```
Dim aa As String = "-5"
Dim bb As String = "-5"
Debug.Print(Val(aa) + Val(bb))
```

because (-5) - (-5) becomes -5 + 5 so its **0**

Answer (score 1):

it is the right answer.
-5 - -5 = 0
if you want to get -10 just do

```
Dim aa = -5
Dim bb = -5
Debug.Print(aa + bb)
```